# Returning a string up until a header

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure why I get this line repeated multiple times when I test this function. Can anyone please help me fix this? I want to return a string up until the header and strip everything afterwards.

```
 "</head>hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner</head>hello python 
world </head> , i'm a beginner</head>hello python world </head> "

def get_header(s):
'''(str) -> str
Return the start of the given string up to and including 
</head>.
>>> get_header("hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner ")
'hello python world </head>'
'''
new_s = ''
tag = '</head>'
for item in s:
    new_s = new_s + tag + s.strip()
return new_s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re
def get_header(s):  
   return re.findall('[\w\s]+\</head\>', s)[0]

print(get_header("hello python world </head> , i'm a beginner "))
```

Output:

```
hello python world </head>
```

Edit: without `re`:

```
def get_header(s):  
    return s[:s.index('</head>')+7]
```

Without hardcoding, you should pass the head value to the function as well:

```
def get_header(s, key):
    return s[:s.index(key)+len(key)]
```

Comment: What does re.findall means

Comment: @bigd `re.findall` is a function contained in the `re` module that allows you to apply regular expressions, or pattern matching, to find matches in strings. In this case, `[\w\s]+\</head\>` is searching for all alphanumeric characters (\w) along with any spaces (\s) up to and including </head>.

Comment: Is there a way do do it without re.findall?

Comment: I mean can I do it without hardcoding? like what if there was just i'm after the head?

Comment: @bigd I added additional code below my most recent edit. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Is key the head value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159177/discussion-between-bigd-and-ajax1234).